# Does Protege API support user rules?

Tags: jena, protege

In Jena API, it says it supports:

"Generic rule reasoner: A rule based reasoner that supports user defined rules. Forward chaining, tabled backward chaining and hybrid execution strategies are supported."

Does Protege API have similar reasoner? The downside of Jena API is it doesn't support full OWL specification.

Comment: [RDF-Protege](https://github.com/sszuev/rdf-protege) - a Jena based Protege fork - might be useful for such kind of cases

Answer (score 1):

Protege uses `OWLReasoner` compliant reasoners, some of which support `SWRL` rules (e.g., HermiT and Pellet). However SWRL rules do not have the same expressive power as the rule based reasoner in the Jena library.

You might want to check out `SWRL` to see if these rules fit your needs: https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/

There is an `SWRLAPI` project which might be relevant:

https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.